# Typescript T[keyof T] of type string

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/mMM8Vm

I got an array of `T` and that has keys of the type `string`. So I want to iterate over all entries in the array and trim the string.

Error:
`Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'`

```
ifAlreadyExists<T>(
    data: Array<T>,
    key: Extract<keyof T, string>,
  ): boolean {

      return (
        data.filter(
          (item) => {
            const v = item[key];

            return v.trim().toLowerCase()
          }
        ).length === 0)
  }
```

How can I tell Typescript that `item[key]` will be of the type string?

Comment: `Extract<keyof T, string>` means the keys which *are* strings, not the keys associated with string values. I'm also not sure why you are calling `filter` with a callback that returns a string instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kaya3 mentioned, your signature constrains `key` to string keys, rather than to keys that have string values. To do the latter, you can introduce a type variable `Key` (which can be any key type), and constrain the array elements to objects that have a string value for the key denoted by `Key` (i.e. `{[K in Key]: string}`):

```
  ifAlreadyExists<Key extends PropertyKey>(
    data: Array<{[K in Key]: string}>,
    key: Key,
  ): boolean {
    ..
  }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oBnYAJ1wDsBzAbmymF2ABsJizLaGcwBDGhADCcAK5VgxKmIC2AIwjkGAXwaYAxq34kSUAIJgwo2WDhUIkjJkYbzXMRuBxyACgCU1nDjtUyUeQREABlcMmJ9cnJ+EAAeeCQAPlQoAG10PCIoAHIAJnzsgBomFnZibIAVUugARiKoASFRCSkoXIBmGqgVAF1eb2AACzCAOlwAM31Wcgh+fBAAUQAPMOASV0CkULJi7OY2CGz3fpwh0YmpmbnFlbJ1zZDV3caRcUkjuigAei+mcGglOQXIwVDYcBdprN5stViRYgBpCAgKAQJbASz4PQABSBkHIoERIESrkYOHw-GA-AiURisXQqXheCoUEJPU4FGoNBUiUKpKgiCRxEJvJw7mIm3Y-GZWD5OBmwDE5GZJO8qqg5MpI3GuFY6LcsrVrhYEFknhQySwaqtUF8-gAbiljbJUgKQH0wdbVfLFcy7SMObIPP64ME4AB3JTCHQQDwG1Wgz3uEbsWhDVAoNAABncIMwoMwFjDBiMJjMFkkHjoQA)

Comment: That looks pretty good, thanks! What if I want to add another parameter to the function that accepts another type? I also tried that, but I can't get it to work with to different types: https://tsplay.dev/mLl5Vm

Comment: @dewey I you accept an answer that took the type signature from my code (even including a later edit!) while leaving out the explanation, then maybe it is more appropriate to direct follow up questions at the author of that answer?

Comment: Oh sorry, thought I accepted the first answer. Since you provided an easy and understandable explanation, I assumed you could also solve the problem from my comment :)

Comment: The order of answers with the same score is randomized by default, as it's perfectly fine to accept a later answer if it's better than a hastily written first one. For an extra key parameter the simple solution won't work anymore, and extending it would be beyond the scope of a comment, so I'd suggest creating a new question for it. That way also others can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the boolean vs string return value in the filter and *deliberately* not constraining `T` to be a `Record<PropertyKey, string>`.

Use a type-guard:

```
  return (
    data.filter(
      (item) => {
        const v = item[key];
        if (typeof v === 'string') {
          return v.trim().toLowerCase();
        }
        return 'something?';
      }
    ).length === 0)
```

For extra points you may want to only expose keys for which the implementation is valid.

`Only` produces a type where for each key of `T` its corresponding field is assignable to `U`.

```
type Only<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

then

```
ifAlreadyExists<T>(
  data: Array<T>,
  key: Only<T, string>, // only keys where values are string-like
): boolean {
  ...
}
```

And there are values other than strings in the Book shape.

```
type Book = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  isbn: number;
  genre: 'fantasy' | 'horror'
};

const bookList: Array<Book> = [{ id: '222', title: 'Title 1', isbn: 1237681231, genre: 'fantasy' }];
this.ifAlreadyExists(bookList, "id"); // fine
this.ifAlreadyExists(bookList, "title"); // fine
this.ifAlreadyExists(bookList, "genre"); // fine
this.ifAlreadyExists(bookList, "isbn"); // Error! isbn is not string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oBnYAJ1wDsBzAbmymF2ABsJizLaGdcSARlWJUArgFsBEcryg0IVchygByAGYBDKsA0kQKqAB9VACzjly5lZgC+DTKEhQA8lVYgAPABUANFACqAHyoGIwA2gDSeFRQiBAgcGpQXgC6xF6RKVAQAB7ACvgkAVAA-FBRIhAAbtK2YXEJSan2AMasukUAgmBgAMJw4mBwVArAoYwtw1yiLcDmABQAlKE4OJNUZFACCIgAMvzAxJ0WGp7wSMFoYeh4RKoATI8qfsxsyipeLOxQAIzPeIJhL97gBmADsADYABw-UE-PzyRTvTTaXT6KA2FKyHDAEz8AB0uDUnVYSg0+BAAFEcgcSPNtkh9mQ-AAiAgsxbYph4kiE4mkiDkqk0sh0hl7A6s17sDlc3EEokkskU6m0+k7JnAVmIpSyxg4nl8pWClUi4BijWSqBswF6nA2TCMRUCoWq0XeQLzfVQfAaHRHE6eLyBHzehrEVzubx+LjUGghxiLYgM9hacarVZKYCicgxL0ZjO+nT4tS4Vj5cj5gsZ+YsCDiZYoYJYavV9abKohOvierxLHe1t4JLzRwQRJQTsoKfW2O0DkrQcFrM5mJVfEUXDiJbruC7OAAd2kvV0ECWA9bDsXmYg2dzqhIAxveNoJRUXOrl9bi3x7FouNQ04AAyLIwDoOpgIz7lA3R9AMQwjNoSx0EAA)